# practical tutorials for learning yii

Tags: yii

My approach to learning a new framework or technology is to read a brief tutorial that goes over how to create a very simple application and then try to build something similar on my own.  I've gone through the definitive guide and it's very hard to digest and doesn't suit my style of learning.

[These](http://www.yiiframework.com/screencasts/) screencasts are excellent but I need more like them!  Does anyone know of anything similar those screencasts or some other relatively brief practical tutorials for Yii?

Answer (score 3):

Try to search for Yii blog, Building a Blog System using Yii, a very simple Yii application